# What is it called when one runs for the second run without touching the crease during the first run?

Tags: rules, cricket, terminology

In today's IPL match, during the Sunrisers Hyderabad's innings, in the last bowl Samad and Sharma ran for two runs. But one of them (I don't remember who exactly), while taking the first run didn't touch the crease and ran for the second. As a result one run was offered to the team.

What is the name of this rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a short run. Quoting from [Law 18](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/scoring-runs):

> 18.3 Short runs
>
> 18.3.1 A run is short if a batsman fails to make good his/her ground in turning for a further run.
>
> 18.3.2 Although a short run shortens the succeeding one, the latter if completed shall not be regarded as short.  A striker setting off for the first run from in front of the popping crease may do so also without penalty.
>
> 18.4 Unintentional short runs
>
> Except in the circumstances of 18.5 [intentional short runs],
>
> 18.4.1 if either batsman runs a short run, the umpire concerned shall, unless a boundary is scored, call and signal Short run as soon as the ball becomes dead and that run shall not be scored.